# Custom Option Distribution per agent created

Tags: distribution, anylogic

I've managed to create a custom option distribution (possible countries to send info) for a group of agents (boutiques), in which any agent created from that type utilizes the distribution to select a country to select the info to, based on the probability.

Like so:

```
Country A : 0.5;
Country B : 0.3;
Country C : 0.2;
```

I have 30 different boutiques, and instead of having one distribution to all of them, I'd like to have a specific custom distribution for each.

as such:

```
Boutique 1                 Boutique 2
Country A : 0.5;           Country A : 0.3;
Country B : 0.3;           Country B : 0.4;
Country C : 0.2;           Country C : 0.3;
```

The option list is the same for any boutique but the probabilities are not.
The boutiques generated are always the same.

I haven't seen a direct option to create such distributions.
Is there a way? Is it possible via java?

Thank you!

Comment: why not making each boutique agent have an individual custom distribution? is that not an obvious solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do here if to create in each one of your boutique agents a variable of type CustomDistributionOfOptions

[image: variable]

the initial value will be based on a function as follows:

```
optionList[] x= new optionList[] { optionList.A, optionList.B, optionList.C };
double [] rates ={2,4,6};
return new CustomDistributionOfOptions(x,rates);
```

of course, you have to replace 2,4 and 6 with your own values that will be individual for each boutique (should be parameters of the agent created)... that you can do by reading a database, an excel or whatever you want